# What are the risk associated while setting file/directory permission to 0777?

Tags: php, permissions

Currently, I am not being able to upload a file to a web folder. Whatever I do, even setting the folder permissions to 0777 I cannot upload the file to it. Out of curiosity, I searched for the risk associated while setting the file permissions as 0777.

Found a question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577514/is-setting-the-uploads-folder-777-permision-secure), but didn't quite had the answer what I was searching for.

I am completely unaware in this subject. What are the risks associated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting 0777 on a `folder` (and I'm talking about a folder here, not a file) doesn't involve any execution security risk like some would state.

`Execute is needed on a directory to access the inode information of the files within.  You need this to search a directory to read the inodes of the files within.  For this reason the execute permission on a directory is often called search permission instead.`

See http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/filepermissions.htm

**The risks are:**

- anybody can read files in this folder (provided the file itself has the `r` permission on the user/group trying to read it, or for `others`)
- anybody can create files in this folder (and optionally execute them, but only the ones created by this specific user)
- anybody can delete files owned by other people in this folder (your files are not secured, whatever owner/permission they have)

If you want to secure some files, you have to create another folder with "normal" permissions (rw for you only, or rw for you and your group) and put your files in it.

On the other hand, nobody could turn a non-executable file into an executable one (chmod  are not permitted if you don't own the file).

**What the risks are not?**

Some people think 0777 is inherited by every file in the folder. This is **wrong**. You can't edit a file if you don't have the `w` permission just because its parent folder is 0777. You can't read a file if it doesn't have the `r` permission.

**How to secure it?**

If you have access to some shell or if your FTP client allows you to change the owner of the files and you know which owner you need, then you could create the folder and set its owner to the apache process (usually, `nobody`, `daemon` or `apache`) and just set 0700 permissions. Problem is, other users, like you when browsing using your FTP client, won't be able to read the files created later by PHP, which is not necessarily an issue.

**OK but what about files?**

I'm not talking about risks inherent to `files` execution because there's no reason you would want to force the `x` permission on a file that shouldn't be executed in the first place.

If some web app needs to write in an existing file, setting it to 0666 (or 0600 if the owner is the apache user) is enough.

Comment: How about "anybody can ALTER specific files in the folder". See the security problem there when the folder contains some executable downloads that people trust and install without posing any questions? :p

Comment: @wimvds Nobody can alter files (delete only), they would need to be 0666 at least or owned by the folks who want to alter it. The 0777 permission of the folder is not inherited by files.

Comment: Of course, the previous comment assumed that the files would be world-writable too (just in case you were wondering)... It just depends on the umask whether or not the default settings would lead to a security disaster or not.

Comment: @wimvds I've edited my answer to make a clear difference between files and folders

Comment: Tell me one thing, when I am creating a directory, using php, Will I be owner or group or user?

Comment: The owner of the directory will be php (I mean, the user apache is running as). The group will be the one apache runs as too. So, it will look like apache:apachegroupe rwxr-xr-x (readable and writeable but apache, readable by the world) But since PHP owns the file, you can set whatever permission or owner/group you want after creation using PHP's `chmod()` and `chown()` functions.

Comment: I do not have any option but to use 0777 as my folder permissions. Everything else will disallow the upload. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: As stated in my answer, you could try to change the owner of the folder and set it to 0700 only (or 0770 is you can change the group only). But if you can't change the owner or the group, you're indeed stuck to 0777.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone who has access to the folder (i.e. the `x` permission on every folder in the path) can read, modify and execute the file.

If it's something that's actually executable there is a high risk of a malicious users adding bad code and then waiting for you to execute it to make you execute some evil code (like creating a copy of `bash` that is set to setuid and executable by the attacker).

If you are on shared hosting, check if 0770 isn't sufficient - if your FTP user is in the same group as the webserver it will be sufficient. In that case the above-mentiones risks usually do not apply since you are never going to execute stuff in an upload target folder and PHP has `open_basedir` to restrict other users from accessing your files. However, if the host also supports CGI scripting (e.g. using Perl) that can be easily circumvented.

Comment: So, even a website visitor can delete the file with 0777 permission.

Comment: When I tried making a directory when the permissions to the folder was 0775, i couldn't. At least finally, I am being able to write on it using 0777. Tell me one thing, when I creating a directory, using php, I will be `owner` or `group` or `user`.

Comment: -1 How do you "execute" a folder? ;-)

Comment: @Starx you could create the folder and set is owner to the apache process (usualy, `nobody`, `daemon` or `apache`) and just set 0700 permissions. Problem is, other users, like you when browsing using your FTP client, won't be able to read the files created by PHP.

Comment: @Capsule: He means the files within the folder.

Comment: The question talks about folders, the subject about file/folder and this answer mixes both ;-) I guess the real question is "what are the risks when setting a folder to 777 so you can allow the PHP process to write files within this folder". @Starx, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Capsule, you are right, My current concern in Folder. But, I would also like to know the risk associated with files.

Comment: @Starx: Then you might want to update  your question's subject. It states "file/directory permission".

Answer (score 0):

I am probably not answering your question regarding the risks, but I can guess why you can't write.

Probably the parent folder doesn't have write access for that user...

use something in line of `chmod ugo+w whateverfile` to the parent folder recursively until you can create files in it :)

Comment: the parent folder doesn't need to be writeable (we are talking about a folder here, not a file). If it was true, then every folder in the full path would need to be writeable by the user running the apache process...

Comment: well, I encountered a problem such that I couldn't transfer files from winscp to a linux system to a folder in `/var/www/cgi-bin/` . So I had to make the www folder to be writeable!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already ruled out some basic PHP security settings (open_basedir restrictions et al) - debugging and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` (make sure you log errors instead of displaying them on production systems) are quite useful to check this :p.

If you set the folder permissions to 777 (world-writable) and a process still can't write to that folder then there could be a MAC implementation running that prevents just that sort of thing (SELinux or AppArmor are likely candidates if you're using Linux). If that's the case then changing the policies they impose will help solving this issue. Setting a folder world-writable is a possible security issue (especially when the folder in question is exposed to the outside world), and also can most likely be avoided.

Comment: YOu are right, But now I can write to the folder, but nothing except giving 0777, will allow me to do that.

Comment: In what regard was I right? The MAC implementation or the PHP based (open_basedir) restrictions? If it's the first, it could help if you specified your OS and the MAC implementation in use.

Comment: You are right, in the regard of what you have assumed.

Comment: Well, if the owner of the folder is set correctly (preferrably to the user/group that is used to run apache/php) then even 700 (or 770 - depending on the setup) should suffice. So it all depends on the configuration of apache/php, and you will have better luck posting this (with all relevant details regarding your configuration) on ServerFault...